# How to find Google sheets API URL?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to figure out how to find the API URL of a google sheet, preferably if I can find it within Google sheets itself instead of making an API call.

This is an example of how it'd look:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1Mslx2H97aiTNhALMJa9rH3N57MxLAmirvXvG_HIutPg/ou8i9q1/private/full

I know the "1Mslx2H97aiTNhALMJa9rH3N57MxLAmirvXvG_HIutPg" is the sheet ID, but I can't figure out where the "ou8i9q1" comes from.

Comment: Please provide the access to the shared file.

Comment: Was my answer useful for you?

Comment: @Tanaike I don't know if Google made an update to their spreadsheets API, but that URL you provided is no longer working with the sheet ID. It worked before and I have screenshots of it and everything. But when I use it today, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. You had confirmed that it worked before. So how about waiting a little? I'm sorry for my poor experiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ou8i9q1` means worksheetId. `od6` means the worksheetId of page 1 of spreadsheet. `od6` is constant.

You can confirm each worksheetId from XML of the following URL.

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/[sheet ID]/public/basic
```

You can see each sheet name at `<title></title>` in the XML. Also you can retrieve worksheetId using the following regex.

```
\/list\/\w+\/(\w+)\/public
```

#### Reference :

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, I don't know if Google made an update to their spreadsheets API, but that URL you provided is no longer working with the sheet ID. It worked before and I have screenshots of it and everything. But when I use it today, it doesn't work.